# Setting up chrooted shell accounts with schroot and debootstrap on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-10.04, chroot

**UPDATE:**

I never did get this figured out. Instead i ended up jsut using `jailkit` since there is a ton (though sometimes outdated) documentation on usage. Id still be interested in knowning how to get `schroot` to work though.

---

IVe found a ton of documentation on setting up schroot/debootstrap as well as a ton of stuff on jailing sftp and some modest instructions for creating a chrooted shell but i cant find anything on get this all working cohesively. Seems like most tutorials are geared towards creating in isolated build environment which is not what i need.

I have schroot set up with an env at `/srv/chroot/systemid`. That works well i can initiate a session fine with `schroot -c systemid -u somejaileduser`.

What i cant seem to get to work properly is chrooting an ssh session. My current configuration looks like this:

```
Match Group jail
   ChrootDirectory /srv/chroot/systemid
   # other stuff to out law tcpforwarding and what not
```

This kind of works in that i get a chrooted ssh session, but it dumps me directly in the chroot as the working directory. I think this is because a session is never actually kicked off and so `/home` never gets bound to `/srv/chroot/systemid/home` (if do `ls /home` in the ssh session its empty).

So are the configuration steps im missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering in many of these cases that instead of jailing each user account, is simply to provide each user with a small virtual machine on the host.

Seems like collecting all the files necessary to have a workable chroot jail on a per user basis is problematic, easily subject to problems and very complex.

Comment: Actually, getting all the files installed is easy using debootstrap.. it does a mini install of an OS in the chroot, and i dont think the problem is missing libs - i thnk the problem is a missing setting somewhere to kick off the schroot session.

Answer (score 0):

[sshd_config](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man5/sshd_config.5.html) has variables you can use with ChrootDirectory.

```
Match Group jail
   # %u is replaced by the username, %h is the full home path
   ChrootDirectory /srv/chroot/systemid/%u
   #ChrootDirectory %h
```